# angularjs accessing ng-repeat checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing ng-repeat to output checkboxes from array.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <label ng-repeat="checkbox_ in checkboxes" class="checkbox"
        for="checkbox_{{$index}}">
            <input name="checkbox_{{$index}}" id="checkbox_{{$index}}"
                ng-model="checkbox_.checked"
                ng-true-value="{checkbox_.value}"
                type="checkbox">
            {{checkbox_.text}}
    </label>
</div>
```

data

```
$scope.checkboxes = [
    {"text": "text1", checked:false},
    {"text": "text2", checked:false},
    {"text": "text3", checked:false},
    {"text": "text4", checked:false}
];
```

After that i want to get access to checkbox_1 for example...

```
<hr>
checkbox_1.checked - {{checkbox_1.checked}}<br>
checkbox_1.value - {{checkbox_1.value}}<br>
checkboxes[1].checked - {{checkboxes[1].checked}}<br>
checkboxes[1].value - {{checkboxess[1].value}}<br>checkbox_1.value - {{checkbox_1.value}}<br>

<div ng-show="checkboxes[1].checked">on</div>
```

And nothing happens
http://jsfiddle.net/MQzGP/3/

How to get access to checkbox1 value 'text2' when user sets it true? ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
you selected <span ng-show="checkboxes[0].checked"> {{checkboxes[0].text}}</span> 
<span ng-show="checkboxes[1].checked"> {{checkboxes[1].text}}</span>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MQzGP/12/)

Or do it dynamically using ng-repeat:

```
you selected <span ng-repeat="checkbox_ in checkboxes" ng-show="checkbox_.checked"> {{checkbox_.text}}</span>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MQzGP/13/)

For separation of concerns and the correct way to work with MVC structure like angularjs. You ***should not*** access your DOM checkboxes directly to get its checked state and text, access the models instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine - except arrays in JS are indexed from 0 not 1. So you should have checkboxes[0].checked instead.

BTW - to debug I suggest to use

```
<pre>{{checkboxes | json}}</pre>
```

Comment: but i want to get access to checkbox_1 not checkbox[1]? where is ng_true_value of it?

Comment: for examle i want to do this <p>You selected {{checkboxes[1].value+' '+checkboxes[2].value}}</p>
and user should see this "You selected text2 text4"